# Business Logic in the JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, stored-procedures

Currently, I am working in a project. I am just following what my old co-employee was doing; they're using ASP.NET (c#) and angularjs. I was surprised that all their business logic was computed in the JavaScript part and just use the c# part to communicate the database. FYI, we are using stored procedures all the time. Is this really a good way of structuring the system?. I want to open up this that perhaps its not a good practice, but I don't have any strong reason, since I came from PHP world.

Comment: The actual question here isn´t about Javascript or C#, but about *where* the code should be executed, on the client or on the server.

Comment: that's right , but i made it that way because its already an existing project.

Comment: Executing business-logic with Javascript  isn´t neccessarily a bad thing, it´s what you mean by the term of a rich or thick client and it´s absolutely fine. It has a few caveats on the traffic which might get quite huge. However in many situtations you *have* to do some data-manipulation on the client-side because you have no access to the servers code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting business logic in JavaScript should be avoided for multiple reasons:

1. **Design**: Mostly, the business layer should be at the server and only UI layer i.e. HTML/JavaScript should be at the disposal of the client-side.
2. **Security**: The more knowledge is available in the public domain, the more chance of a threat to the application.
3. **Maintenance**: Business objects can be reused more effectively than embedding the business logic in JavaScript. Often I have seen each .aspx page has its own set of JavaScript files. This may not always hold true.

Comment: thanks for this, maybe now I have some valid reason to defend :)

Answer (score 1):

We don't know enough of your business to fully evaluate how bad this is, but it sounds terrible.

For one thing you're shipping your entire business logic to customers and competitors alike, on every request.

The biggest drawback is of course that you're forced to assume that all business logic has been executed. Everything that happens on the client side is highly exposed to being tampered with by the client.

Are you saying there is no server side enforcement of any business rules? If you were to receive an order of all the items in your inventory, with a price set to $1, you would just accept that, ship the items and invoice the customer $1?

Comment: sounds like that, as I said all business logic, computations, data validations were done in  the javascript file, i admit at first I was shocked because as far as I know, business logic should be done in the server script.

Comment: @Fred: Is it a public site? Do you have a link? Perhaps we can produce some convincing arguments :)

Comment: no sir, as of the moment not yet accessible in the web.

Comment: @Fred: At least that's one layer of security then :)